# Some part of view is not rendered while navigating back to the page SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I've a hierarchy of 3 pages. When I'm navigating back from 3rd page to 2nd page(Product) it doesn't render completely. Only for first time navigation forward works fine. If I back navigate from 3rd page to first then navigation from category to product also not rendering the 2nd page. 
 [image: Some Columnts Were not rendered]

**The XML of Product page is as follows** `

```
<mvc:View xmlns:common="sap.suite.ui.commons" xmlns:m="sap.m" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    controllerName="dlesDLESdashboard.controller.Solution.SolutionDetail" xmlns:dles="dlesDLESdashboard.control" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout">
    <Page xmlns="sap.m" title="Detail" id="SolutionDetail" class="solutionDetail" backgroundDesign="Standard" showNavButton="true"
        navButtonPress="onNavBack">
        <customHeader>
            <Bar id="__bar2_copy2">
                <contentLeft>
                    <Button id="lijsld" tooltip="back" icon="sap-icon://nav-back" press=".onNavBack" activeIcon="sap-icon://nav-back"/>
                    <Label class="HeaderFont" text="Detail" labelFor="input-b" design="Bold"/>
                </contentLeft>
                <contentMiddle>
                    <Title text="Course ID : {dlesScore>ID}" width="100%"/>
                </contentMiddle>
                <contentRight></contentRight>
            </Bar>
        </customHeader>
        <Bar id="bar2">
            <contentLeft>
                <Label text=" {dlesScore>LJ_SOLUTION}" labelFor="input-b"/>
            </contentLeft>
            <contentMiddle>
                <Label text="Course Owners : Stephen Howard" labelFor="input-b"/>
            </contentMiddle>
        </Bar>
        <Bar>
            <contentMiddle>
                <Label text="17 June 2017" labelFor="input-b"/>
            </contentMiddle>
            <contentRight>
                <Link class="toolbarUserText" text="Print" press=".linkToContributions"/>
            </contentRight>
            <contentRight>
                <Link class="toolbarUserText" text="About" press=".handleCourseClick"/>
            </contentRight>
            <contentRight>
                <Link class="toolbarUserText" text="Contacts" press=".linkToContributions"/>
            </contentRight>
        </Bar>
        <l:Grid class="sapUiSmallMarginTop" defaultSpan="L4 M6 S12" id="courseDetailsGridLayout">
            <l:content>
                <Panel class="courseContent">
                    <dles:DLESYourScoreTile topic="" dles="{dlesScore>DLES}" id="solutionDetailDLES"></dles:DLESYourScoreTile>
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData id="gld222" span="L6 M6 S12"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Panel>
                <Panel class="courseContent" height="100%">
                    <dles:NPSScoreTile topic="" nps="55"></dles:NPSScoreTile>
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData id="gld221" span="L6 M6 S12"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Panel>
                <Panel class="courseContent" height="1000px">
                    <content>
                        <TabContainer id="tabcourseDetail" class="monitoringLandscapeSelector peddingLeftRight">
                            <items>
                                <TabContainerItem id="solutionCourses" name="Courses">
                                    <content>
                                        <TileContainer id="idCoursesContainer">
                                            <tiles>
                                                <dles:ScoreTile name="{Score>name} Responses" topicId="{Score>ID}" topic="{Score>SOLUTION}" result="{Score>RESULT}"
                                                    id="tileDLESCourse" press=".handleCourseClick"></dles:DLESScoreTile>
                                            </tiles>
                                        </TileContainer>
                                    </content>
                                </TabContainerItem>
                                <TabContainerItem id="idJournies" name="Journies">
                                    <content></content>
                                </TabContainerItem>
                            </items>
                        </TabContainer>
                    </content>
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData id="gld2212" span="L12 M12 S12"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Panel>
            </l:content>
        </l:Grid>
    </Page>
</mvc:View>`
```

when I"m clicking on navigation the following event fired  the same method is used on 2nd page navegation for navigation to other page

```
handleCourseClick: function(oEvent) {
            var that = this;
            //get the current tile detial eg course id that can be sent to next page.
            var s = oEvent.getSource();
            var topic = s.getProperty("topicId");
            this.getRouter().navTo("solution", {
                solutionId: topic
            });
        },
```

for navigation back,

```
onNavBack: function(oEvent) {
        var oHistory, sPreviousHash, oRouter;
        // in some cases we could display a certain target when the back button is pressed
        if (this._oData && this._oData.fromTarget) {
            this.getRouter().getTargets().display(this._oData.fromTarget);
            delete this._oData.fromTarget;
            return;
        }
        // call the parent's onNavBack
        BaseController.prototype.onNavBack.apply(this, arguments);
    },
```

and my menifest.js code is as

```
"routes": [
                {
                    "pattern": "",
                    "name": "appHome",
                    "target": "home"
                },
                {
                    "pattern": "solution/{solutionId}",
                    "name": "solution",
                    "target": "solution"
                },
                {
                    "pattern": "course/{courseId}",
                    "name": "course",
                    "target": "course"
                }
            ],
            "targets": {
                "home": {
                    "viewName": "Home",
                    "viewLevel": 1
                },
                "notFound": {
                    "viewName": "NotFound",
                    "transition": "show"
                },
                "solution": {
                    "viewPath": "dlesDLESdashboard.view.Solution",
                    "viewName": "SolutionDetail",
                    "viewLevel": 2
                },
                "course": {
                    "viewPath": "dlesDLESdashboard.view.Course",
                    "viewName": "CourseDetail",
                    "viewLevel": 3
                }
            }
`
```

and my baseController navBack methos is as

```
        onNavBack: function (oEvent) {
        var oHistory, sPreviousHash;
        oHistory = History.getInstance();
        sPreviousHash = oHistory.getPreviousHash();
        if (sPreviousHash !== undefined) {
            window.history.go(-1);
        } else {
            this.getRouter().navTo("appHome", {}, true /*no history*/);
        }
    }
```

Comment: add the controller code also

Comment: @santhosh I've updated the code. I hope I've added everything. reguired. but still if you dont understand I can provide you more detail

Comment: Are you declaring onNavBack inside your controller

Comment: By seeing this I think the base controller also has the same function name and even the controller..So it will collide , change the name of the onNavBack function in your controller and update in the view

Comment: I've tried by changing the function name in my controller, in both cases it navigate back to my previous page. But it is not re-rendering my controls  and the Error is Element `sap.suite.ui.microchart.ColumnMicroChart#__chart0 Chart overflow - Some columns were not rendered `

Comment: Why are you using this => delete this._oData.fromTarget;

Comment: I'm using the example code from SAPUI5 documentation, I don't understand 100% code.but if i remove this or add it make no change.

Comment: Do you think something is wrong in routing?

Comment: can you add the nav back view code which is having the micro chart control

Comment: the XML on the top is of the same view. `<dles:ScoreTile name="{Score>name} Responses" topicId="{Score>ID}" topic="{Score>SOLUTION}" result="{Score>RESULT}"
                                                    id="tileDLESCourse" press=".handleCourseClick"></dles:DLESScoreTile>` is a custom control, I've created. I"ve not included any microchart in this control . its just a simple Html, css tags

Comment: But the error that you are getting denotes micro chart in it so I asked about that. Commenting control by control and check the navigation process could solve your problem I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't wrap your tab controlinto gridview. put tab control outside the gridview. and remove panel tages in the xml view of your page. the best way is to remove one by one control and check.